# How to open an event loop in discord.py?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I am making a loop for my discord bot and it will DM the user every ten minutes. I keep getting an error that my event loop is closed. I do not know how to open it. Help will be very appreciated. My code is shown below.

```
@bot.command(aliases=['r10', 'R10'])
async def remind10(ctx, user):
    mbed = discord.Embed(title = 'Reminding you every ten minutes.', description = 'If you want to deactivate this, please say the command pp!stopremind')
    mbed.set_author(name = 'Procrastination Police')
    await ctx.send(embed=mbed)
    global remind_loop
    @tasks.loop(minutes=10)
    async def remind_loop():
        await user.send('Reminding you to stop procrastinating?')
```

Comment: The tasks loop should be separate from a command. You should also use a storing method so that you can do this with multiple people

Answer (score 0):

No offence but these are your problems,

- First, you are not calling the task, so it wouldn't run.
- Second, why is remind_loop global, what is the point?
- Third, you aren't passing in the variable user and mbed for the remind_loop.
- Fourth, why are you sending only 'Reminding you to stop procrastinating?' to the user when it would be more logical to have all the texts together.
- Fifth, remind10(ctx, user) would be better if it was remind(ctx, user : discord.Member)
- Sixth, Its more clear to have the tasks function outside of the main function and in some scenarios you cant have the task inside of the function.

Anyways I made 2 versions of want you wanted.

The first one requires the user to have admin perms because people could just do it on other people. If you only type "pp!remind" it will remind yourself every 10 minutes (600 seconds) until you type "pp!remind stop". Else if you type "pp!remind @[Username] start [interval(in seconds)]", it will remind the user you typed in every interval that you typed in. e.g. "pp!remind @Bob start 60". If you wanted to stop reminding that specific user you would type "pp!remind @[Username] stop".

The second one doesn't require adim perms because this reminder only works on yourself. If you type in "pp!remind" it will remind yourself every 10 minutes(600 seconds) until you type "pp!remind stop". Else if you type in "pp!remind start [interval]" then it would remind you every interval. e.g. "pp!remind start 600"(10 mins). To stop it running just type "pp!remind stop" and nothing else.

1.

```
@bot.command(aliases = ["r","R"])
@commands.has_permissions(administrator = True)
async def remind(ctx,member : discord.Member = "", enabled = "start", interval = 600):
    if member == "":
        member = bot.get_user(ctx.author.id)
    if enabled.lower() == "stop":
        reminder.cancel()
    elif enabled.lower() == "start":
        mbed = discord.Embed(title = f'Reminding you to stop procrastinating every {interval / 60} minutes.', description = 'If you want to deactivate this, ask an admin to enter the command pp!remind stop @[Username]')
        mbed.set_author(name = 'Procrastination Police')
        reminder.change_interval(seconds = float(interval))
        reminder.start(member, mbed)
        
@tasks.loop(seconds = 600)
async def reminder(member, mbed):
    await member.send(embed=mbed)
```

2. 

```
@bot.command(aliases = ["r","R"])
async def remind(ctx, enabled = "start", interval = 600):
    member = bot.get_user(ctx.author.id)
    if enabled.lower() == "stop":
        reminder.cancel()
    elif enabled.lower() == "start":
        mbed = discord.Embed(title = f'Reminding you to stop procrastinating every {interval / 60} minutes.', description = 'If you want to deactivate this, enter the command pp!remind stop')
        mbed.set_author(name = 'Procrastination Police')
        reminder.change_interval(seconds = float(interval))
        reminder.start(member, mbed)
        
@tasks.loop(seconds = 600)
async def reminder(member, mbed):
    await member.send(embed=mbed)
```

Comment: Hello! Thank you for responding and sorry for replying late. I just wanted to ask and tell you that the code you sent had an error stating that member had no attribute as send. Do you know why it said that? I don't think it makes sense because when you defined member, you included the author of the message's ID which was the user and still there was no attribute to send the message.

Comment: Hello, sorry for replying late. I decided to add this function for my own discord bot and it works perfectly fine. I heard that if you are using discord rewrite, the send function is actually send_message. Otherwise im unsure what the problem is as I am not that experienced with discord.py .

Comment: I am using this code for the task:

@tasks.loop(seconds = 600)

async def reminder(member, interval):

    mbed = discord.Embed(title = f'Reminding you to stop procrastinating every 

{interval / 60} minutes.', description = 'If you want to deactivate this, ask an admin to 

enter the command pp!remind stop @[Username]')

    mbed.set_author(name = 'Procrastination Police')

    await member.send(embed=mbed)

Comment: And I am using this in the on_ready function because I only want this to work for myself:

    guild = client.get_guild(850027913461366834)
    owner = client.get_user(guild.owner.id)
    interval = 600
    reminder.change_interval(seconds = interval)
    reminder.start(member = owner, interval = interval)

Comment: I am also using client instead of bot because im using this:

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = prefix, intents = intents)

Comment: Thank you for replying. I should have replied again saying that I fixed it by defining the member variable as ctx.author only. I was just wondering, do you have any possible method so that other users can use it too?  I tested the loop out and it did work but only for myself and not other people.

Comment: Well I explained it in the answer but the first chunk of code lets you enter a members name e.g @Atrixium but you need admin permissions for the code to work as people can just use it on other people. The second chunk of code only works on the person using the command

Comment: Oh I just realized what you mean, you get an error saying that the task isnt finished. Sorry I don't know how to fix that, maybe post  another question on stack overflow or search youtube. Sorry, like I said I'm not that experienced with the discord module.